# Split one row into two based on other table row value

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

I have two table as below

### First Table

```
CID      Cmonth      Amount
---------------------------
1        JAN         15000
2        JAN         5000
3        JAN         5000
4        FEB         20000
5        MAR         15000
```

### Second Table

```
SerialNo  EmpID     Cmonth      Amount
--------------------------------------
1         111        JAN        11000
2         222        JAN         7000
3         333        JAN         7000
4         111        FEB        10000
5         222        FEB         5000
6         333        FEB         5000
7         111        MAR        10000
8         222        MAR         5000
9         333        MAR         5000
```

### Expected Output

```
SerialNo  EmpID     Cmonth     Amount       CID
-----------------------------------------------
1         111        JAN        11000        1
2         222        JAN         4000        1
2         222        JAN         3000        2
3         333        JAN         2000        2
3         333        JAN         5000        3
4         111        FEB        10000        4
5         222        FEB         5000        4
6         333        FEB         5000        4
7         111        MAR        10000        5
8         222        MAR         5000        5
9         333        MAR         5000        5
```

I don't want to use cursor or while loop. Is there any other way. Open for any suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you explain the logic to achive that output? I can go Indiana Jones and try to archological discover it, but my time is valuable.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: What is the logic for getting the epxected output?

Comment: Its like getting a running total of  **amount** column from second table and  comparing with First table(based on month), whenever its reached the limit of first table Amount value I have to split amount between two different CID and continue.

Comment: There must be an order in which you're applying these. Is that `EmpID`? That seems like an odd thing to order things on. Maybe it's `SerialNo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you most of the way there. There might be an easier/faster/better way to do this with a recursive CTE, but this approach was the first thing that I tried.

There's currently one "bug", but you didn't seem to address this case in your question. The buckets for March only come to 15000, but the amounts total 20000 for that month. In your final output you assigned the last amount to the last CID, but that isn't clear from any explanation, so for now I've left this as-is:

```
;WITH CTE_RunningTotals AS
(
    SELECT
        SerialNo,
        EmpID,
        Cmonth,
        Amount,
        SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Cmonth ORDER BY SerialNo) AS RunningAmount
    FROM
        Deposits
),
CTE_RunningTotalsWithLast AS
(
    SELECT SerialNo, EmpID, Cmonth, Amount, RunningAmount, LAG(RunningAmount, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Cmonth ORDER BY SerialNo) AS LastRunningAmount FROM CTE_RunningTotals
),
CTE_LimitTotals AS
(
    SELECT CID, Cmonth, SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Cmonth ORDER BY CID) AS RunningAmount FROM Limits
),
CTE_LimitTotalsWithLast AS
(
    SELECT
        CID, Cmonth, RunningAmount,
        LAG(RunningAmount, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Cmonth ORDER BY CID) AS LastRunningAmount,
        LAG(CID) OVER (PARTITION BY Cmonth ORDER BY CID) AS LastCID
    FROM
        CTE_LimitTotals
)
SELECT
    D.SerialNo,
    D.EmpID,
    D.Cmonth,
    CASE WHEN D.Amount < D.RunningAmount - L.LastRunningAmount THEN D.Amount ELSE D.RunningAmount - L.LastRunningAmount END AS Amount,
    L.CID
FROM
    CTE_RunningTotalsWithLast D
INNER JOIN CTE_LimitTotalsWithLast L ON
    L.Cmonth = D.Cmonth AND
    D.RunningAmount > L.LastRunningAmount AND
    D.RunningAmount <= L.RunningAmount
UNION ALL
SELECT
    D.SerialNo,
    D.EmpID,
    D.Cmonth,
    L.LastRunningAmount - D.LastRunningAmount,
    L.LastCID AS CID
FROM
    CTE_RunningTotalsWithLast D
INNER JOIN CTE_LimitTotalsWithLast L ON
    L.Cmonth = D.Cmonth AND
    D.LastRunningAmount < L.LastRunningAmount AND
    D.RunningAmount >= L.LastRunningAmount
ORDER BY
    D.SerialNo
```

Comment: Hi Tom. Did you read `running total` and know how the expected result is generated?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I was able to figure it out from the sample data/output if that's what you mean. This is a problem that I've seen before, although in slightly different varieties.

Comment: Its ok, I just couldnt see any pattern there.